# Aix: How to generate valid sha1/sha256/sha512 password hash on AIX /etc/security/passwd?

Tags: algorithm, hash, passwords, aix, crypt

AIX, like other Unix, only store a salted hash of user password. 
In the old days, it uses to use DES crypt, and then a (slighty different version of) MD5 Crypt, the same that you will find on Linux.

With more recent version of AIX and the use of /etc/security/passwd, you can use new SHA1/SHA256/SHA512 hashes. They look like that (with example hash string result for the password "secret"):

```
- salted sha1   : {ssha1}12$tyiOfoE4WXucUfh/$1olYn48enIIKGOOs0ve/GE.k.sF
- salted ssha256: {ssha256}12$tyiOfoE4WXucUfh/$YDkcqbY5oKk4lwQ4pVKPy8o4MqcfVpp1ZxxvSfP0.wS
- salted ssha512: {ssha512}10$tyiOfoE4WXucUfh/$qaLbOhKx3fwIu93Hkh4Z89Vr.otLYEhRGN3b3SAZFD3mtxhqWZmY2iJKf0KB/5fuwlERv14pIN9h4XRAZtWH..
```

The config file /etc/security/pwdalg.cfg explain the the number after {algo_name} is the "num_cost", and we can get the number of iteration used in the hashing function with 2^num_cost.

I need to generate valid hash from a Scala application that are latter place in /etc/security/passwd.

I tried to adapt commons-codec Sha2Crypt (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/Sha2Crypt.html) witch implements the official Sha-Crypt algorithm (https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt), but that give the wrong hash.

Anybody knows what should be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that, appart for md5, which is the standard unix implementation and differs only for the prefix ({smd5} in place of "$1", the other implementations differ SIGNIFICANTLY from standard Unix crypt described at https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt. In fact, they only kept:

- the number of bytes (and so chars) for the hash: 20 for ssha1, 32 for ssha256, 64 for ssh512
- the base64 encoding table (which is not the standard one but starts with "./012" etc

What changed is:

- they use PBKDF2 HMAC-(sha1, sha256, sha512) in place of Sha-Crypt,
- they use a different padding table
- the number of iterations, named "rounds" in Unix crypt vocabulary, is not the number N found at the begining of the hash string (after the algo name). The number of iteration is actually  2^N, and N is called in /etc/security/pwdalg.cfg the "cost"

A valid Scala implementation can be found in Rudder's `AixPasswordHashAlgo.scala` here: https://github.com/Normation/rudder/blob/master/webapp/sources/rudder/rudder-core/src/main/scala/com/normation/cfclerk/domain/AixPasswordHashAlgo.scala